# Strange XHTML Strict 1.0 Drop-Down Bug

Tags: debugging, drop-down-menu, xhtml

A few days back, I started programming a converter in XHTML Strict 1.0. Whilst I was making the drop downs, I realised that there were random blank spaces in between the selections. Is there any way that I could fix it? Here is my rather simple yet long code: (Notes: It's a work in progress so please ignore all of the random drop down selections :D. Also I am using google chorme. Lastly, It's ok if you can only fix it using javascript.)

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html lang="EN" dit="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xml; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>UKConverter</title>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
        </script>
      </head>
      
      <body>
        <h1>Converter!</h1>
        <form action = "">
          <p>
            <label>UK or US units?<label>
            <select id = "country">
              <option value = "UK">UK</option>
              <option value = "US">US</option>
            </select>  
          </p>
          
          <p>
            <label>Which type of category?</label>
            <select id = "catergory">
              <option value = "temperature">Temperature</option>
              <option value = "volume">Volume</option>
              <option value = "distance">Distance</option>
              <option value = "weight">Weight</option>
              <option value = "area">Area</option>
              <option value = "speed">Speed</option>
              <option value = "dataByte">Data byte</option>
              <option value = "time">Time</option>
            </select>
          </p>  
            
          <p> 
            <label>What type of unit would you like to convert from?<label>
            <select id = "temperature">
              <option value = "celsius">Celsius</option> 
              <option value = "fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
           <option value = "kelvin">Kelvin</option>
           <option value = "reaumur">Reaumur</option>
           <option value = "newton">Newton</option>  
           <option value = "rankine">Rankine<option>
            </select>  
          </p>
          
          <p> 
            <label>What type of unit would you like to convert from?<label>
            <select id = "volumeUK">
              <option value = "cubicMeter">Cubic meter</option> 
              <option value = "cubicDecimeter">Cubic decimeter</option>
           <option value = "cubicCentimeter">Cubic centimeter</option>
           <option value = "liter">Liter</option>
           <option value = "deciliter">Deciliter</option>  
           <option value = "centiliter">Centiliter<option>
           <option value = "milliliter">Milliliter</option> 
              <option value = "cubicInch">Cubic inch</option>
           <option value = "cubicFoot">Cubic foot</option>
           <option value = "cubicYard">Cubic yard</option>
           <option value = "gallon">Gallon</option>  
           <option value = "oilBarrel">Oil barrel<option>
           <option value = "pint">Pint<option>
            </select>  
          </p>
          
          <p> 
            <label>What type of unit would you like to convert from?<label>
            <select id = "volumeUS">
              <option value = "cubicMeter">Cubic meter</option> 
              <option value = "cubicDecimeter">Cubic decimeter</option>
           <option value = "cubicCentimeter">Cubic centimeter</option>
           <option value = "liter">Liter</option>
           <option value = "deciliter">Deciliter</option>  
           <option value = "centiliter">Centiliter<option>
           <option value = "milliliter">Milliliter</option> 
              <option value = "cubicInch">Cubic inch</option>
           <option value = "cubicFoot">Cubic foot</option>
           <option value = "cubicYard">Cubic yard</option>
           <option value = "gallon">Gallon</option>  
           <option value = "oilBarrel">Oil barrel<option>
           <option value = "fluidPint">Fluid pint<option>
           <option value = "dryPint">Dry pint<option>
            </select>  
          </p>
          
          <p> 
            <label>What type of unit would you like to convert from?<label>
            <select id = "distance">
              <option value = "kilometer">Kilometer</option> 
              <option value = "meter">Meter</option>
           <option value = "decimeter">Decimeter</option>
           <option value = "centimeter">Centimeter</option>
           <option value = "millimeter">Millimeter</option>  
           <option value = "mile">Mile<option>
           <option value = "inch">Inch</option>
           <option value = "foot">Foot</option>
           <option value = "yard">Yard</option>  
           <option value = "nauticalMile">Nautical mile<option>
            </select>  
          </p>
          
          <p> 
            <label>What type of unit would you like to convert from?<label>
            <select id = "weight">
              <option value = "tonne">Tonne</option> 
              <option value = "kilogram">Kilogram</option>
           <option value = "hectogram">Hectogram</option>
           <option value = "gram">Gram</option>
           <option value = "decigram">Decigram</option>  
           <option value = "centigram">Centigram<option>
           <option value = "milligram">Milligram</option> 
              <option value = "microgram">Microgram</option>
           <option value = "carat">Carat</option>
           <option value = "grain">Grain</option>
           <option value = "ounce">Ounce</option>  
           <option value = "pound">Pound<option>
            </select>  
          </p>
          
          <p> 
            <label>What type of unit would you like to convert from?<label>
            <select id = "typeOfUnit">
              <option value = "celsius">Celsius</option> 
              <option value = "fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
           <option value = "kelvin">Kelvin</option>
           <option value = "reaumur">Reaumur</option>
           <option value = "newton">Newton</option>  
           <option value = "rankine">Rankine<option>
            </select>  
          </p>
          
          <p> 
            <label>What type of unit would you like to convert to?<label>
            <select id = "typeOfUnit">
              <option value = "celsius">Celsius</option> 
              <option value = "fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
           <option value = "kelvin">Kelvin</option>
           <option value = "reaumur">Reaumur</option>
           <option value = "newton">Newton</option>  
           <option value = "rankine">Rankine<option>
            </select>  
          </p>
          
          <p> 
            <label>What type of unit would you like to convert from?<label>
            <select id = "typeOfUnit">
              <option value = "celsius">Celsius</option> 
              <option value = "fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
           <option value = "kelvin">Kelvin</option>
           <option value = "reaumur">Reaumur</option>
           <option value = "newton">Newton</option>  
           <option value = "rankine">Rankine<option>
            </select>  
          </p>
          
          <p> 
            <label>What type of unit would you like to convert to?<label>
            <select id = "typeOfUnit">
              <option value = "celsius">Celsius</option> 
              <option value = "fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
           <option value = "kelvin">Kelvin</option>
           <option value = "reaumur">Reaumur</option>
           <option value = "newton">Newton</option>  
           <option value = "rankine">Rankine<option>
            </select>  
          </p>
          
          <p> 
            <label>What type of unit would you like to convert from?<label>
            <select id = "typeOfUnit">
              <option value = "celsius">Celsius</option> 
              <option value = "fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
           <option value = "kelvin">Kelvin</option>
           <option value = "reaumur">Reaumur</option>
           <option value = "newton">Newton</option>  
           <option value = "rankine">Rankine<option>
            </select>  
          </p>
          
          <p> 
            <label>What type of unit would you like to convert to?<label>
            <select id = "typeOfUnit">
              <option value = "celsius">Celsius</option> 
              <option value = "fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
           <option value = "kelvin">Kelvin</option>
           <option value = "reaumur">Reaumur</option>
           <option value = "newton">Newton</option>  
           <option value = "rankine">Rankine<option>
            </select>  
          </p>
          
          <p> 
            <label>What type of unit would you like to convert from?<label>
            <select id = "typeOfUnit">
              <option value = "celsius">Celsius</option> 
              <option value = "fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
           <option value = "kelvin">Kelvin</option>
           <option value = "reaumur">Reaumur</option>
           <option value = "newton">Newton</option>  
           <option value = "rankine">Rankine<option>
            </select>  
          </p>
          
          <p> 
            <label>What type of unit would you like to convert to?<label>
            <select id = "typeOfUnit">
              <option value = "celsius">Celsius</option> 
              <option value = "fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
           <option value = "kelvin">Kelvin</option>
           <option value = "reaumur">Reaumur</option>
           <option value = "newton">Newton</option>  
           <option value = "rankine">Rankine<option>
            </select>  
          </p>
          
          <p> 
            <label>What type of unit would you like to convert from?<label>
            <select id = "typeOfUnit">
              <option value = "celsius">Celsius</option> 
              <option value = "fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
           <option value = "kelvin">Kelvin</option>
           <option value = "reaumur">Reaumur</option>
           <option value = "newton">Newton</option>  
           <option value = "rankine">Rankine<option>
            </select>  
          </p>
          
          <p> 
            <label>What type of unit would you like to convert to?<label>
            <select id = "typeOfUnit">
              <option value = "celsius">Celsius</option> 
              <option value = "fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
           <option value = "kelvin">Kelvin</option>
           <option value = "reaumur">Reaumur</option>
           <option value = "newton">Newton</option>  
           <option value = "rankine">Rankine<option>
            </select>  
          </p>
          
          <p> 
            <label>What type of unit would you like to convert from?<label>
            <select id = "typeOfUnit">
              <option value = "celsius">Celsius</option> 
              <option value = "fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
           <option value = "kelvin">Kelvin</option>
           <option value = "reaumur">Reaumur</option>
           <option value = "newton">Newton</option>  
           <option value = "rankine">Rankine<option>
            </select>  
          </p>
          
          <p> 
            <label>What type of unit would you like to convert to?<label>
            <select id = "typeOfUnit">
              <option value = "celsius">Celsius</option> 
              <option value = "fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
           <option value = "kelvin">Kelvin</option>
           <option value = "reaumur">Reaumur</option>
           <option value = "newton">Newton</option>  
           <option value = "rankine">Rankine<option>
            </select>  
          </p>
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If you were to save this as an actual XHTML file (i.e. with an .xhtml extension) and then load it into a browser, the browser itself would immediately point you to where the first error is. Also, the MIME type of an XHTML file needs to be `application/xhtml+xml` rather than `text/xml`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your HTML is not well formed. There are missing closing tags for the block elements `<option>`.

In most cases I saw the empty items in the drop down it was because there was a missing a closing `</option>` for the opening `<option>`.

There are several validation tools to determine the well formed-ness. Or you could utilize an IDE with syntax highlighting.

- [W3 Validator](https://validator.w3.org/check)
- [Aptana IDE](http://www.aptana.com/)

Comment: Thanks! I was way too stupid to notice :D *Facepalms*